# Canvas loses style when I create Fabric.js canvas object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have a Canvas Object with top and left attributes defined through with a previous JavaScript function but when I create a fabric Canvas object

```
  var fabricCanvas= new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas');
```

my HTML Canvas has top and left attributes set on 0.

I have tried setting the top and left attributes after the creation of fabric Canvas object through a script but when I do this the canvas changes position but the fabric function (selection and moving functions) remain where the canvas was located previously (where fabric Canvas has positioned it)!

What can I do to resolve this conflict? Is there a way to keep equal the canvas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a canvas with Fabric.js it wraps it in a div and adds a second `<canvas>` (used to select the objects rendered in the first canvas). This is explained in the [wiki page](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/How-fabric-canvas-layering-works) of Fabric.js. If you want to position your canvas apply CSS rules to the parent div element which is of the class "canvas-container".

Comment: I was unable to over-ride fabric's positioning of the canvas.

Comment: canvas-container class is not overriding, its not applying any css to this div.

Comment: @PiyushDholariya I think you are using the CSS in js or something that scoped CSS, actually, I was using fabric with vue.js and facing the same issue but when I moved my `canvas-container` CSS rule to global file it works

Answer (score 0):

**answer from my [identical thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089839/fabric-js-how-to-center-canvas/15091349#15091349)**

> apply
>
> ```
> margin: 0 auto;
> ```
>
> to class = canvas-container
>
> canvas-container is automatically created by fabric.
>
> see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8AB3D/34/)

Comment: canvas-container class is not overriding, its not applying any css to this div

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that if your using some kind of css preprocessor (for me it was scss stylesheet inside Angular) - targeting the "canvas-container" class inside the component scss file will not work. For me the workaround was the general project css file.

Answer (score 0):

You may override the canvas-container class upon initialization like so:

```
new fabric.Canvas('canvasId', {containerClass: 'custom-container-class'});
```

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#containerClass