# fabric.js ... how to center canvas

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

fabricjs will convert:

```
//  this DOM structure
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</div>

//  to this:
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="canvas-container">
    <canvas class="upper-canvas"></canvas>
    <canvas class="lower-canvas" id="c"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

... see [this explanation](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/How-fabric-canvas-layering-works)

Because of the way fabric js wraps a canvas  element, how do you keep a canvas horizontally centered.

here is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261918/canvas-loses-style-when-i-create-fabricjs-canvas-object). here is a [fiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/8AB3D/33/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

apply

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to class = canvas-container

canvas-container is automatically created by fabric.

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8AB3D/34/)

Comment: how can we also align vertically?  `margin :auto auto` not working . it is align horizontally but not vertically.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Angular, use the project's **general stylesheet** (instead of the component stylesheet) to provide the css rules as @dsdsdsdsd described `.canvas-container {your styles..}`. otherwise your styles may not apply.